# When setting process affinity to CPU 0, for a sample threading code, CPU 0 usage goes to 100%, but setting affinity to all processors distributes load

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, cpu-cores

I am an Engineering student and I am trying to learn about multiprocessing and threading in Python so please correct me if I am wrong.
As far as I know, when creating new threads you deal with one core that switches between threads concurrently, but you normally do not get to choose which core. So, setting affinity to a core in task manager and observing the performance of that core shows that the performance goes to 100%. Therefore, I assumed that when setting affinity to all processors only one core should reach 100% usage. However, I found that that was not the case.

The code used:

```
from threading import Thread
import os
import math
import time
start_time = time.perf_counter() 
def calc():
    for i in range(0, 4000000):
        math.sqrt(i)

threads = []

for i in range(os.cpu_count()):
    print('registering thread %d' % i)
    threads.append(Thread(target=calc))

for thread in threads:
    thread.start()

for thread in threads:
    thread.join()

print(time.perf_counter() - start_time)
```

When I set affinity to core 0, this [graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgWW3.png) appears.
When I set affinity to all processors, this [graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lEp8.png) appears.
The total CPU usage graph is almost the same in both cases and the runtime is almost the same in both cases as well.

Why isn't the second graph the same as the first? Are threads distributed between cores? if so, how is the runtime the same? does the thread in core X wait for the thread in core Y to finish? Is this just a Python thing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Re, "As far as I know, when creating new threads you deal with one core..." That generally is not true. In most operating systems, If the process hasn't assigned specific "affinities" to its different threads, then the OS can run different threads of the same process on different CPUs at the same time, and it can move a thread from one CPU to another any time the OS decides that that's a good thing to do.

Comment: Python is a special case though: The Python interpreter uses a big global mutex (a.k.a., "[The GIL](https://realpython.com/python-gil/)") that prevents any two threads from simultaneously accessing most of the program state. That means that even though the threads of a pure Python program might run on different CPUs, the program will never be able to use more CPU _cycles_ on a multi-processor machine than it could use on a single-processor machine. The mere fact that the GIL _exists_ changes the semantics of the language, so don't expect it to go away any time soon.

Comment: @SolomonSlow So, when I create the threads, it doesn't assign which core handles which thread, it only decides when it's that thread's turn; unless I set the affinity, in that case, it can only "control" that core, right?

Comment: @SolomonSlow To be frank, I still can't fully understand the idea behind mutex and GIL, but I appreciate your answer and the level of detail you have included. Thank you so much!

Comment: Mutex is a simple idea: Only one thread can ever keep a mutex "locked" at any given instant in time. If thread A tries to lock the mutex when thread B already owns it, then the `lock()` function will not return in thread A until thread B releases it. You can use that to protect shared data. If one thread needs to temporarily put shared data into a bad state before advancing it to the next good state, then it should lock the mutex while doing that work. If every other thread locks the mutex even when just _looking_ at the data, then they will never see the bad state.

Comment: I see. Thank you so much for your time and the great explanation!

Comment: In every other language except Python, on a multi-CPU computer, the program should use a mutex to access shared data even in simple cases where there is no "temporary bad state." The reason is complicated (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistency_model). But in Python programs, because of the GIL, programmers don't have to be so careful. That's why the GIL can never go away. Some existing Python programs would break if you tried to run them on a "Python" system that didn't need a GIL to protect its own, internal data.

Comment: @SolomonSlow if the CPython implementers are sufficiently ruthless they can just say that those programs are buggy and always were, in that they are improperly relying on undocumented behavior of a particular implementation of Python.  (perhaps the CPython implementers are not that ruthless, but after watching the Python 2->3 transition I wouldn't put it past them ;) )